# MVC Razor View - Using Model in .EditorFor() and for in String.Format()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

```
<td>@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Loan)</td>
```

I have that in the beginning of the view, and then after that, I have a statement like

```
The interest rate for the loan is @String.Format("{0:c}", Model.Interest).
```

It gives me error "'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model'"

I also tried

```
The interest rate for the loan is @String.Format("{0:c}", Model => Model.Interest).
```

It errored "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object[]' because it is not a delegate type"

If I remove the EditorFor, it doesn't error for the next statement.

Is there any way I can do both, other than adding the model to the ViewBag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument name in the lambda expression is conflicting with the existing `Model` property.

You need to use a different argument name, such as `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Loan)`

Comment: Thanks, that works. I thought the @model at the top of the view page is declaration of the variable.

Comment: I remember seeing "x => x.Property" example as well, if that works, does this mean all Lambda expression refers to Model? Or all undeclared variable using like m or x, would refer to the model?

Comment: Neither.  A lambda expression is a function that takes an argument named `x` or `m` or whatever.  The name of the argument is totally irrelevant. Most MVC helper methods take lambda expressions that receive the model as their parameter.